# Reformat array in <select> tag

Tags: php, mysql, html

I fetched record from mysql and resultent is in array:

```
Array ( [Logodesign] => 130 [Webdesign] => 80 [Printdesign] => 72 [Illustrationdesign] => 49 [iPhoneportfolio] => 23 )
```

and I want to show all categories with their total rows in  tag like

[image]

to do so i coded:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT 
    SUM(IF(cat = 'logodesignportfolio',1,0)) AS Logodesign, 
    SUM(IF(cat = 'websitedesignportfolio',1,0)) AS Webdesign, 
    SUM(IF(cat = 'printdesignportfolio',1,0)) AS Printdesign, 
    SUM(IF(cat = 'illustrationdesignportfolio',1,0)) AS Illustrationdesign, 
    SUM(IF(cat = 'iphoneportfolio',1,0)) AS iPhoneportfolio 
    FROM portfolio");
$f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
print_r($f);
echo "<br />";
echo "<select>";
foreach($f as $k){
    echo "<option>".$f.' - '.$k."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

but it shows:
[image]

Comment: That's because `$f` is an array. Did you meen `foreach($f as $k => $v)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
foreach($f as $k => $a){
    echo "<option>".$k.' - '.$a."</option>";
}
```

Comment: why then you asked the question muhammad!

Comment: Well after submittig I just think more seriously and then I found what I missed. :)

Comment: so you have posted it as answer!!